# Php that should add +1 to a file name instead moves file to the back

Tags: php

So I have a bit of an issue. I'm trying to create something that once ran will check if the file it's trying to save as exists, if it exists then it renames the existing file its number +1, and what it's suppose to do is if that file exists then rename that file.
So basically
1(A) 2(B) 3(C)
Save file X as 1
1(X) 2(A) 3(B) 4(C)

But currently instead of that it's moving the first file being renamed to the last number and I'm unsure how to fix it.
What it's doing
1(A) 2(B) 3(C)
Save file X as 1
1(X) 2(B) 3(C) 4(A)

```
<?php
ob_start(); ?>

<html>
All HTML here
</html>

<?php 
$path = "cache/home-".$imputnum.".html";
?>


<?php

if (file_exists($path))     { 
        $i=$imputnum; 
        $new_path=$path;

        while (file_exists($new_path)) 
        { 
            $extension = "html"; 
            $filename = "home"; 
            $directory = "cache";

            $new_path = $directory . '/' . $filename . '-' . $i . '.' . $extension; 


            $i++;  
        } 

        if(!rename($path, $new_path)){
            echo 'error renaming file';
        }
    }
?>

<?php
$fp = fopen("cache/home-".$imputnum.".html", 'w');
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are already 3 files, you'll need to rename all 3 of them.. For instance

```
x-3.ext -> x-4.ext
x-2.ext -> x-3.ext
x-1.ext -> x-2.ext
```

(from last to first). So, the `rename` must be inside a loop.

Here's an example:

```
function save_file( $name, $ext, $content ) {
        $f = "$name.$ext";
        $i = 0;
        while ( file_exists( $f ) )
                $f = "$name-".++$i.".$ext";

        while ( $i > 0 )
                rename( $name.(--$i==0?"":"-$i").".$ext", "$name-".($i+1).".$ext" );

        file_put_contents( "$name.$ext", $content );
}

save_file( "home", "html", "A" );
save_file( "home", "html", "AB" );
save_file( "home", "html", "ABC" );
save_file( "home", "html", "ABCD" );
```

After this is run, we have:

```
home.html:   "ABCD"
home-1.html: "ABC"
home-2.html: "AB"
home-3.html: "A"
```

Comment: Seems this works well, I am running in to something odd though, after about 3 files created, if something is adding in to the middle it'll delete the earliest page made.

Comment: What do you mean with "if something is adding in to the middle"?

Comment: What I mean is if it's placed anywhere but the last number. Such as if the file is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, if X is placed between 2 and 3 (or anything else) file 1 will strangely delete itself.

Comment: Well, I don't know - I'd have to see the code. The above algorithm finds the last numbered file and renames them all the way back to the beginning, freeing up `$name.$ext`. If you then decide to overwrite one of the numbered files instead of prepend, you'd also have to change the second `while ( $i > 0 )` to `while ( $i > $thenumber_to_insert )`.

Comment: That was it, can't believe I didn't think about that, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

here's a snippet of how i did it

```
// Get a unique filename
$filename = "$IMAGES_DIR/UploadedImg.$ext";
while(file_exists($filename)){
    $chunks = explode(".", $filename);
    $extention = array_pop($chunks);
    $basename = implode(".", $chunks);
    $num = isset($num) ? ($num+1) : 0;
    $filename = "$basename$num.$extention";
    if(file_exists($filename)) $filename = "$basename.$extention";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do sounds like a job for array_unshift which prepends to an array. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

After inserting the base file name without numbers into the array, I would loop through the array and append/prepend the index like so:

```
$filenames = $exising_filenames;
array_unshift($filenames, $new_filename);
foreach($filenames as $index => &$filename {
    // Do some operation to remove the numbers from filename here.

    // Now add back the number using the array's index.
    $filename = ($index+1).$filename;

    // You may rename the existing files using the filenames.
}
// Insert the new file with filename using $filenames[0]
```